# c# List<T>.Contains() Method Returns False

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the code block below I would expect dictCars to contain:
{ Chevy:Camaro, Dodge:Charger }

But, dictCars comes back empty.  Because this line returns false each time it's called:

```
if(myCars.Contains(new Car(Convert.ToInt64(strCar.Split(':')[1]),strCar.Split(':')[2])))
```

Code block:

```
public class Car
{
    public long CarID { get; set; }

    public string CarName { get; set; }

    public Car(long CarID, string CarName)
    {
        this.CarID = CarID;
        this.CarName = CarName;
    }
}

List<Car> myCars = new List<Car>();
myCars.Add(new Car(0,"Pinto"));
myCars.Add(new Car(2,"Camaro"));
myCars.Add(new Car(3,"Charger"));

Dictionary<string, string> dictCars = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string strCars = "Ford:1:Mustang,Chevy:2:Camaro,Dodge:3:Charger";
String[] arrCars = strCars.Split(',');
foreach (string strCar in arrCars)
{
    if(myCars.Contains(new Car(Convert.ToInt64(strCar.Split(':')[1]),strCar.Split(':')[2])))
    {
        if (!dictCars.ContainsKey(strCar.Split(':')[0]))
        {
            dictCars.Add(strCar.Split(':')[0], strCar.Split(':')[2]);
        }
    }
}

return dictCars;
```

**Question:  What am I doing wrong with my List.Contains implementation?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, this is as you wrote `if (new Car(1,"car") == new Car(1,"car")) { ... }` and expected that the code `...` ever gets executed. Without implementation of special methods and operators this will never be true for reference types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code, by implementing `IEquatable`

```
public class Car: IEquatable<Car>
{

    ......

    public bool Equals( Car other )
    {
        return this.CarID  == other.CarID && this.CarName == other.CarName;
    }
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/ms131187.aspx

Comment: I found this msdn example  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx right after I posted the question.  Thanks Candie!

Comment: I'am happy to help you s15199d

Answer (score 8):

You need to tell Contains what makes two `Car`s equal.  By default it will use `ReferenceEquals` which will only call two objects equal *if they are the same instance*.

Either override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your `Car` class or define an `IEqualityComparer<Car>` class and pass that to `Contains`.

If two `Car`s that have the same `CarID` are "equal" then the implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
   if(o.GetType() != typeof(Car))
     return false;

   return (this.CarID == ((Car)o).CarID);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return CarID.GetHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `Car` class is a reference type. By default reference types are compared to each other *by reference*, meaning they are considered the same if they reference the same instance in memory. In your case you want them to be considered equal if they contain the same values.

To change the equality behavior, you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

If two cars are equal only when `ID` and `Name` are equal, the following is one possible implementation of the equality members:

```
protected bool Equals(Car other)
{
    return CarID == other.CarID && string.Equals(CarName, other.CarName);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        return true;
    var other = obj as Car;
    return other != null && Equals(other);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (CarID.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ 
                (CarName != null ? CarName.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

This implementation has been created automatically by ReSharper.
It takes into account `null` values and the possibility of sub-classes of `Car`. Additionally, it provides a useful implementation of `GetHashCode`.

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that two Car instances that have the same CarID and CarName are equal.

This is incorrect. By default, each `new Car(...)` is *different* from each other car, since they are references to different objects.

There are a few ways to "fix" that:

- **Use a [`struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx) instead of a `class` for your Car.**

  Structs inherit `ValueType`'s default implementation of `Equals`, which compares all fields and properties to determine equality.

  Note that in this case, it is recommended that you make your `Car` struct immutable to [avoid common problems with mutable structs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441309/87698).
- **[Override Equals and GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/371328/87698).**

  That way, `List.Contains` will know that you intend Cars with the same ID and Name to be equal.
- **Use another method instead of `List.Contains`.**

  For example, [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) allows you to specify a predicate that can be matched:

  ```
  bool exists = myCars.Any(car => car.ID == Convert.ToInt64(strCar.Split(':')[1])
                                  && car.Name = strCar.Split(':')[2]);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the IEqualityComparer

More information on how to do it can be found here;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx

```
// Custom comparer for the class 
 class CarComparer : IEqualityComparer<Car>
{
// Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal. 
public bool Equals(Car x, Car y)
{

    //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data. 
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

    //Check whether any of the compared objects is null. 
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        return false;

    //Check whether the properties are equal. 
    return x.CarID == y.CarID && x.CarName == y.CarName;
}

// If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
// then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects. 

public int GetHashCode(Car car)
{
    //Check whether the object is null 
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(car, null)) return 0;

    //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
    string hashCarName = car.CarName == null ? 0 : car.CarName.GetHashCode();

    //Get hash code for the ID field. 
    int hashCarID = car.CarID.GetHashCode();

    //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
    return hashCarName ^ hashCarID;
}
```

Check for equality;

```
CarComparer carComp = new CarComparer();
bool blnIsEqual = CarList1.Contains(CarList2, carComp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx). Most probably as:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
     Car car = obj as Car;
     if(car == null) return false;
     return car.CarID == this.CarID && car.CarName == this.CarName;
}
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but it could be because [overriding only Equals but not GetHashCode is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/q/371328/87698) and can lead to unexpected problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your car class needs to implement interface IEquatable and define an Equals method, otherwise the contains method is comparing the underlying references.

Answer (score 0):

A collection can never "contain" a newly `new`ed object which uses the default `Object.Equals` comparison. (The default comparison is `ReferenceEquals`, which simply compares instances. This will never be true comparing an existing `Car` with a `new Car()`)

To use `Contains` in this way, you will need to either:

1. Override `Car.Equals` (and `Car.GetHashCode`) to specify what it means to be equivalent, or
2. Implement an `IEqualityComparer<Car>` to compare the instances and specify that in your call to `Contains`.

Note the side effect that in the first option, other uses of `Car.Equals(Car)` will also use this comparison.

---

Otherwise, you can use `Any` and specify the comparison yourself (but IMHO this smells a little funny - a Car should know how to compare itself):

```
if(myCars.Any(c=> c.CarID == Convert.ToInt64(strCar.Split(':')[1]) && c.CarName == strCar.Split(':')[2]))
```

Comment: "Note the side effect that in the first option, other uses of Car == Car will also use this comparison.": That is not correct. If you don't explicitly override the equality operator, it will still perform a reference comparison.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You're right. Edited. You're supposed to read what I *mean* not what I type!! :-P

Comment: Hehe, alright. There is another error: You can't pass an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to `List<T>.Contains`.

Comment: Aha, that's the one you want to use. You are right, that works, but that's not the `Contains` method in `List<T>`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yup, but I didn't say `List<T>.Contains`, I just said "Contains" (I think) :-D

Answer (score -1):

```
myCars.Contains(newCar)
myCars.Where(c =>  c.CarID == newCar.CarID && c.CarName==newCar.CarName).Count() > 0
```